# node.js and aws-sdk : Error 'Cannot read property 'Stream' of undefined(…)'

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-sdk

Before I started using webpack, I was able to use the aws-sdk to read from an aws S3 bucket. After switching to webpack to build similar functionality as a web app, I had to use this solution to get things working: http://andrewhfarmer.com/aws-sdk-with-webpack/

I've gotten as far as being able create my AWS object now, but I can't seem to instantiate a readstream. When the web application comes up (and errors out), I tried these on the debug console:

```
   > foo = new AWS.S3();
    f…s.constructor {config: Config, isGlobalEndpoint: false, endpoint: Endpoint, _clientId: 2}
   > bar = foo.getObject({Bucket: "mybucketname", Key: "some/resourcenamehere.json"});
    Request {domain: undefined, service: f…s.constructor, operation: "getObject", params: Object, httpRequest: HttpRequest…}
```

So far so good. but then:

```
  >  mystream = bar.createReadStream();
    aws-sdk.js?085a:86247 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Stream' of undefined(…)
```

My js / node / webpack skills aren't great, really just reading and hacking as I go, so I'm not sure what to try next. The Request object or whatever ***does*** have a createReadStream method in its **proto** so I'm confused.

Comment: Just to clarify: nothing has change in terms of endpoints, credentials etc. Used to work with vanilla node, now doesn't work in web app.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/browser/ and make sure the example is set up including CORS.  Then adapt the working example to your application.

Comment: hmm... that url is not loading for me... EDIT: works when I request as http:// first, then it redirects to the https:// url fine. weird. OK will have a look and do as suggested; hope to report back soon...

Comment: My first problem: "CORS needs to be configured on the Amazon S3 bucket to be accessed directly from JavaScript in the browser." I don't think I have that kind of control over this bucket; corporate. but maybe its already implemented. I'll ask..